# setValue does not work when using react-hook-form and react-dropzone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, react-dropzone

When using react-hook-form and react-dropzone, the form parameter is not updated after setValue.

The setValue set for onDrop does not register a value.

If the first argument of setValue is entered as an appropriate string, the value is set, but if the first argument is the name attribute of the form received from props (e.g., aaaaa), the value is set.

Please let me know how to solve this problem.

```js
export default function FileUpload(props:Props){
    return (
        <Controller
            control={props.control}
            name={props.name}
            render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur,value }}) => (
                <Dropzone
                    noClick
                    onDrop={(acceptedFiles) => {
                        console.log(props.setValue);
                        props.setValue(props.name, acceptedFiles[0]);
                    }}
                >
                    {({
                          getRootProps,
                          getInputProps,
                          open,
                          isDragActive,
                          acceptedFiles,
                      }) => (
                        <div>
                            <div
                                style={{
                                    borderStyle: 'dashed',
                                    backgroundColor: isDragActive ? `#808080` : 'transparent',
                                }}
                                {...getRootProps()}
                            >
                                <Input
                                    type={"hidden"}
                                    {...getInputProps({
                                        // type: 'hidden',
                                        // id: 'spreadsheet',
                                        onBlur,
                                        onChange,
                                    })}
                                />
                                <Stack className={"mx-1 mt-1"}>
                                    <PrimaryButton type="button" onClick={open}>
                                        ファイルを選択
                                    </PrimaryButton>
                                    <Typography fontSize={15}>またはドラッグ＆ドロップ</Typography>
                                    <Typography fontSize={15}>{acceptedFiles.length!==0&&acceptedFiles[0].name}</Typography>
                                </Stack>
                            </div>
                            {props.errors && props.name in props.errors && <Typography className={"mt-1.5 ml-3 text-xs"} color={'#d32f2f'}>{props.errors && props.errors[props.name]?.message}</Typography>}
                        </div>
                    )}
                </Dropzone>
            )}
        />

    );
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I am facing the same issue. Thank you in advance and regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the onChange func coming from the props of the controller.

```
onDrop={(acceptedFiles) => onChange(acceptedFiles[0])
```

Comment: This did not work.